# Once locked, screen stays black and cannot be unlocked

Tags: release-freya, settings, greeter

When locked, my laptop (Ideapad Y510P, with proprietary Nvidia drivers installed) screen just turns off. The laptop is still on, but I cannot access the lock screen to unlock. The only thing I can do is push the power button, which will shutdown the system. I cannot access a tty, and is unresponsive. My GPU is a GT750M. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Did this happen with the FOSS drivers as well? How did you install the proprietary nvidia drivers?

Comment: This appear for me on t420 with loki too. With Logout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Run `sudo -i scratch-text-editor /etc/default/acpi-support`
- Find and change `POST_VIDEO=true` to `POST_VIDEO=false`
- Find and change `SAVE_VBE_STATE=true` to `SAVE_VBE_STATE=false`
- Restart your laptop, issue should be solved.

Source:[Blog](http://www.amitsrivastava.net/2008-03-23-hibernate-suspend-resolved-ubuntu-gutsy-nvidia-dell-vostro/), [Ubuntu Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-restricted-modules-2.6.20/+bug/109529), Worked on mine.

Comment: This works under a certain condition for me. If I suspend the laptop at least once after it has been started up, then the lock screen issue does not come up. If this was not done, then I run into the same issue. Once I get the black lockscreen, the laptop is still running (the power light is one, and I can hear the fans), however I cannot suspend by closing the laptop lid. I can only shut it down using the power button. If I do happen to suspend at least once after start up, then the lock screen seems to work perfectly fine, no black screen.

Comment: This worked for me.
I'm running Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM] GPU in a Dell OptiPlex 9020

Answer (score -1):

Alternately you can type the login password and click enter when you see the black screen.