# Black Screen with Cursor When Waking elementary OS from Suspension

Tags: suspend

I'm facing an issue with Freya.

Every time my Lenovo Y50-70 is suspended and then waked it shows a black screen with cursor.

I am unable to type anything nor use alt+shift+ to access the terminal. The computer simply stays frozen and I am forced to power it off and boot again.

How can I fix this black screen issue?

Comment: I have the same problem with Loki, I have all updates.

Answer (score 1):

This was a confirmed [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-restricted-modules-2.6.20/+bug/109529) in Elementary OS Freya when using nvidia-glx module. I had resolved it by following [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/586/once-locked-screen-stays-black-and-cannot-be-unlocked) post.

```
Run sudo -i scratch-text-editor /etc/default/acpi-support
Find and change POST_VIDEO=true to POST_VIDEO=false
Find and change SAVE_VBE_STATE=true to SAVE_VBE_STATE=false
Restart your laptop, issue should be solved.
```

I think that this is fixed in Loki.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue for quite a while now, Maybe they have fixed this on the Loki update.
To solve your issue i have found that pressing the f buttons (f5, f6 f7) solves the problem, not sure why, nor which one specifically does the trick

Comment: for me it was solved by the latest update